# What does "Introduce A to B" mean?

Tags: meaning

Does it mean to let A know B or let B know A?

In my spoken English class, the teacher says: "I'll introduce all classmates to you". He means he wants to let the classmates know me.

My question is: shouldn't he say "I will introduce you to all the classmates" instead?

Comment: [to have the classmates meet me.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your teacher is introducing you to each member of the class individually then there is no difference, he is introducing them to you and you to them.

> Joe this is Charles, Charles this is Joe. Joe this is Jim, Jim this is Joe. .....

If it is to the class as a whole then he is **introducing you to the class**

> Class this is Joe.

Answer (score 1):

"Introducing A to B" means telling B a little about A, usually at a first meeting.

So  the teacher introduces the class to you by telling you something about the class. Introducing you to the class tells them something about you.

I think a good teacher would do both.

Comment: Thank you so much, you give me confidence to argue with my spoken teacher.

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to be polite when you raise this with your teacher. Perhaps "argue" is the wrong word for what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your remind again